# how to declare punch of array variable in Excel using PHPExcel??/

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I got values of column A and B from Excel by below php code

```
 for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
{
$col_A = array(trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["A"])); 

$col_B =array(trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["B"])); 
}
```

If 'A' has 44 variable names and 'B' has 44 values.

In this scenario,How can I assign the values of 'B' to the variable names of 'A'
Please help me to solve this

Comment: A                              B                                                                     country_code             HK
country_name             Hong Kong
month                     February
year                             2017
date                             1/2/2017
promoters_in_total      54
downloaded_the_app   54
download_percentage  100%                                                                   here I need to assign each data of 'A' toeach value of 'b'.For instance,country_code=HK and country_name=Hong Kong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in PHP can take on two different key-types and they can mix and match. Indexed by number and indexed by string. And an array can contain any value, including an array of values.  This means that you can create an array that uses the names in Array A as the keys and the values in Array B as the values for those keys.

```
$columns = [];
// Arrays start at 0, but since these came from excel 0 is the column header.
// You want to stop 1 entry before the count of your array. Since arrays are 0 indexed, the array count is 1 larger than the last index.
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount-1;$i++)
{
    $a = trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["A"]);
    $b = trim($allDataInSheet [$i]["B"]);
    // You don't need to specify the Array constructor anymore. 
    // You can just use brackets to create a new array.
    // Not sure if you still want these, but I left them for you.
    $col_A = [$a]; 
    $col_B = [$b]; 

    // Assign the values of B to columns in A
    if(!isset($columns[$a]) {
        $columns[$a] = $b;
    } else {
      // Debugging message - Tried to set two values to the same name.
    }
} 
// Do stuff with $columns
// $columns["a"] == "b"
```

Above, you can see that since $allDataInSheet[$i]["A"] is the string we want, we can just use that value as our key and its matching entry in B as the value for that key.

Notice how we don't let a value get added to the array if we already have that name set. If you want $columns[$a] to be an array of values, you can change it to look like this:

```
if(!isset($columns[$a]){
    // If we don't have an entry for $columns[$a] create an array here to hold the values for possible $b's.
    $columns[$a] = [];
}

// Add $b to the $columns[$a] array.
$columns[$a][] = $b;
```

That will treat the $columns array as an array of arrays. Meaning that each position can hold multiple values. So, we turn it into an array and just add the $b value to that position.  If we come across that $a value again, we'll see that we already have that position set and we just use the array that's already there.

Notice - we do an isset check instead of an empty check because if 'b' was actually " " or false or 0 or for some strange reason, $columns[$a] doesn't change from an empty array to an array with something in it, than we don't want to erase the value that's already there.

Good Luck!

Comment: Great..!!! Thanks for help me in advance.I got a error like   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['  near by $columns = [];  can you help me to know what the issue here please

Comment: A                              B                                                                     country_code             HK
country_name             Hong Kong
month                     February
year                             2017
date                             1/2/2017
promoters_in_total      54
downloaded_the_app   54
download_percentage  100%

Comment: A                              B                                                                     country_code             HK
country_name             Hong Kong
month                     February
year                             2017
date                             1/2/2017
promoters_in_total      54
downloaded_the_app   54
download_percentage  100%                                                                   here I need to assign each data of 'A' toeach value of 'b'.For instance,country_code=HK and country_name=Hong Kong.

Comment: ---- "Great..!!! Thanks for help me in advance.I got a error like PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' near by $columns = []; can you help me to know what the issue here please – avudaiappan T 17 hours ago " 

---- Can you copy-paste your code over?